# javascript detect scrollbar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I know this question has been asked ad nauseum, but I am stumped because after trying several different solutions, I still cannot get my script to properly detect the scrollbar.

Here is the function I currently am using to try and detect a scrollbar:

```
function checkScrollBar() {
  var hContent = $("body").height(); // get the height of your content
  var hWindow = $(window).height(); // get the height of the visitor's browser window

  if(hContent>hWindow) { // if the height of your content is bigger than the height of the browser window, we have a scroll bar
    return true;    
  }

  return false;
}
```

the problem is that even though on my page there is literally a vertical scrollbar popping up because the content of the page is longer than the window on my laptop, this function still says that the window height is equal to the body height.

I am still newer to javascript/jQuery, so please be gentle if there is a major error I have missed.

Comment: replace `body` with `document` !

Comment: @adeneo Great! that is great. I am trying to understand though why body did not work?

Comment: @jcsbrotha You can't directly select the body tag. It's better to select the document tag.

Comment: @jcsbrotha - The body height can be set with CSS, and can be anything really, as long as the content overflows. Using the documents height will usually work better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the offset of the page.

```
function checkScrollBar() {
  var hContent = $(document).height(); // get the height of your content
  var hWindow = $(window).height(); // get the height of the visitor's browser window

  if(hContent>hWindow) { // if the height of your content is bigger than the height of the browser window, we have a scroll bar
    return true;    
  }

  return false;
}
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/a2rnd/

Comment: @jcsbrotha IF my question is the correct one, click the tick bellow to upvotes/downvotes, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a little plugin for it.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

use it like this,

```
$('#my_div1').hasScrollBar(); // returns true if there's a `vertical` scrollbar, false otherwise..
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/p3FFL/)

tested working on Firefox, Chrome, IE6,7,8